# Using Ethers.js and Metamask SDK in mobile browser

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I'm trying to avoid using Deep Linking from my app to Metamask mobile app to run my web dapp on the Built-In browser and keep the user on the native browser. In order to do this, I find out that `await web3Modal.connect()` doesn't work as it relays on `window.ethereum` and it doesn't handles mobile correctly, opening the Metamask App as expected.

In order to do this, I used the `MetaMask SDK` which handles correctly the connection to the Metamask Mobile App

```
import MetaMaskSDK from '@metamask/sdk';

const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK(options);

// This opens the app correctly, ask form permission, and gets back to the browser
const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();

ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts', params: [] });
```

My problem is that as I'm using Ethers.js to interact with my Smart Contracts, at some point I need to instantiate the Contract and pass a signer to it, in order to be able to send transactions. However, I can't make Ethers.js work with the `Metamask SDK` provider

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
```

Anyone has faced the same issue and was able to solve it?